# clear all messages in certain channel on_load

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When I'm playing with my bot I do everything in a "bottesting" channel only I have access to, I'm trying to figure out how to get the bot on load to purge or delete all the messages currently in that certain channel

I've tried to make the `bot.say(!clear)` its own command to clear the channel but it won't recognize its output, I currently have to manually do the clear command I have set up for others to use

```
@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    #bot announces to me when its online and posts in bottesting channel
    await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id=bottesting), 'Im Back ' + myid)
    print('<',datetime.datetime.now(),'>',NaMe," Launched")

This is what my current on_ready looks like and as of now it just posts that it is online and tags me in the post and the channel as well as outputs to cmd with print.
```

Comment: Maybe it would be best to factor the logic of your clear command into another coroutine, and then call that coroutine from both on_ready and clear.

Comment: still learning python, so gonna have to read up on coroutines, dont think ive used one yet, if so it wasnt intentional haha

Comment: Coroutines are `async def` functions.  I just mean make something you can call from the two separate places, passing the relevant information (the channel to clear) from each

Comment: ah ok i get ya that makes sense, just somewhere to make and store something that can be called? if i could just get the bot to call itself id be done or even figure out a uncallable auto command on_ready

Comment: Actually, can I see your `clear` command?  Depending on how it's set up, this might be fairly easy.

Comment: formatting may be a bit off when pasted:

`@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True, manage_messages=True, manage_roles=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=1):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    messages = []    
    async for message in bot.logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount)+1):
        messages.append(message)
    await bot.delete_messages(messages)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could turn `clear` into a seperate coroutine that can be called from both places:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True) 
@has_permissions(administrator=True, manage_messages=True, manage_roles=True) 
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=1): 
    await _clear(ctx.message.channel, amount)  # Technically you could apply the decorators directly 
                                               # to the _clear callback, but that's a little complicated

async def _clear(channel, amount=1):
    messages = [] 
    async for message in bot.logs_from(channel, limit=amount+1):     
        messages.append(message) 
    await bot.delete_messages(messages)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel("123")
    await _clear(channel, 100)
```

Comment: that did it! huge thanks man! that was a weeks worth of headache lol